# Automated conversion from string concatenation to formatted arguments

Tags: java, regex

Our code is littered with things like,

```
Log.d("Hello there " + x + ", I see your are " + y + " years old!");
```

I want to be able to script the conversion to something like this,

```
Log.d("Hello there %s, I see your are %d years old!", x, y);
```

(Note: I'm not worried about getting the right argument type now. I could pre-process the file to determine the types, or convert to always use strings. Not my concern right now.)

I am wondering if anyone has tackled this. I came up with these regexs for pulling out the static and variable parts of the strings,

```
static final Pattern P1 = Pattern.compile("\\s*(\".*?\")\\s*");
static final Pattern P2 = Pattern.compile("\\s*\\+?\\s*([^\\+]+)\\s*\\+?\\s*");
```

By looping on `find()` for each I can pull out the parts,

- "Hello there "
- ", I see your are "
- "years old!"

and,

- x
- y

But I can't come up with a good way to piece these back together, considering all the possibilities of how they might be concatenated together.

Maybe this is the wrong approach. Should I be trying to pull out, then replace the variable part with the format argument?

Comment: Even if there would be regex for translating it, just by seeing `x` and `y` you cannot figure out (without checking the logic) if you should use `%s` , `%d` - or anything else.

Comment: How do you know to use `%s` or `%d` or `%f` ?

Comment: yes, the format type isn't the part i'm worried about right now. i could pre-process the file and determine the type of the variable. right now it's more about constructing the formatted string with the qualifiers in the right locations.

Comment: Hmm, maybe a silly idea. Any chance to grep out all those `Log.d` calls into a file and arrange them such the they compile and can get executed in a context where you set the variables before to `%s`, then run it and somehow, replace the results for the originals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex to capture all the arguments and strings together in one go. Therefore you can figure out exactly where the arguments are meant to fit into the overall string using the pairings.

`(?:(\w+)\s*\+\s*)?"((?:[^"\\]|\\.)*+)"(?:\s*\+\s*(\w+))?`
[Regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/lB2fW2/5). (Thanks to [nhahtdh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1400768/nhahtdh) for the improved version.)

It will find all the concatenations as part of Log.d in the format:
`[<variable> +] <string> [+ <variable>]`
Where `[]` denotes an optional part.

With that you can form the appropriate replacements, take the following example:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.lang.StringBuilder;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String log = "Log.d(\"Hello there \" + x + \", I see your are \" + y + \" years old!\");";
    System.out.println("Input: " + log);
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:(\\w+)\\s*\\+\\s*)?\"((?:[^\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*+)\"(?:\\s*\\+\\s*(\\w+))?");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(log);
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(25);
    List<String> arguments = new ArrayList<String>(5);
    output.append("Log.d(\"");
    while (m.find()) {
        if (m.group(1) != null) {
            output.append("%s");
            arguments.add(m.group(1));
        }
        output.append(m.group(2));
        if (m.group(3) != null) {
            output.append("%s");
            arguments.add(m.group(3));
        }
    }
    output.append("\"");
    for (String arg : arguments) {
        output.append(", ").append(arg);
    }
    output.append(");");
    System.out.println("Output: " + output);
  }
}
```

> Input: Log.d("Hello there " + x + ", I see your are " + y + " years old!");
>   Output: Log.d("Hello there %s, I see your are %s years old!", x, y);

[Java demo here](http://repl.it/yu3/5).

Comment: Your Regex fails, if there are escaped `\"`s, such as `Log.d("Value was \"" + x + "\"")`

Comment: `(?<!\\)` is a patchy fix at best, since it doesn't know how many ``\`` there are before the `"`. For string literal, you should use the regex `"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*+"`

Comment: @nhahtdh In this situation it doesn't really matter how many are in front of `"`. Only an odd number of backslashes preceding the quotations would make for a valid string in java. But if you want to go for thoroughness I guess your way would be best.

Comment: @nhahtdh True, I will adjust my solution later. Thanks.

Comment: The rewritten regex based on yours: https://regex101.com/r/lB2fW2/4 (there is no need for lazy quantifier - actually all of the quantifiers can be made possessive, but I only make the one for the string literal possessive)

Comment: @nhahtdh I've updated my answer, just had to add a capturing group to the string part of your regex. I thought lazy quantifiers would help in terms of efficiency but it seems they do the opposite in this case. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you would replace everything to `%s`, you could do this:
(ps.: Assuming well formatted code in terms of whitespaces)

Keep resolving from RIGHT to LEFT, as parameter position is important.

1.) Run this regex to resolve everything of the form `Log.d({something} + var)` to `Log.d({something}, var)`

```
(Log\.d\(.*?)\"\s*\+\s*([^\s]+)(\+)?(\))
```

with replacement

```
$1%s", $2$4
```

(https://regex101.com/r/hY2iK6/8)

2.) Now, You need to take care about every variable occuring between strings:

Keep running this regex, until no replacements appear:

```
(Log\.d\(.*)(\"\s*\+\s*([^\s]+)\s*\+\s*\")(.*?\"),([^\"]+);
```

with replacement

```
$1%s$4,$3,$5;
```

After run 1: https://regex101.com/r/hY2iK6/10

After run 2: https://regex101.com/r/hY2iK6/11

3.) Finally, you need to resolve the Strings containing a leading variable - which is no problem:

```
(Log\.d\()([^\"]+)\s+\+\s*\"(.*?),([^"]+;)
```

with replacement

```
$1"%s$3,$2,$4
```

https://regex101.com/r/hY2iK6/9

There might be cases *not* covered, but it should give you an idea.

I added the `Log.d` to the matchgroups as well as its part of the replacement, so you could as well use `Log\.(?:d|f|e)` if you like,

Comment: thanks for the well thought out response. unfortunately there were two.